# Accessing stack variable slower than dereferencing pointer?

Tags: c++, performance, testing, heap-memory, stack-memory

I ran two tests which perform the same operation: Add N random numbers.  Test_1 uses an int on the stack, Test_2 uses an int on the heap.  Surprisingly, on my machine Test_1 runs at around 945ms, Test_2 runs around 915ms (while timings may vary, the difference is very consistent and noticeable).  What would explain such a significant difference?  I used g++ with -O2 and -O3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  constexpr int N = 100000000;
  int x = 0; // TEST_1
  //int* p = new int; //TEST_2
  auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    x += rand(); //TEST_1
    //*p += rand(); // TEST_2
  }
  auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  cout << x << endl; // TEST_1
  //cout << *p << endl; //TEST_2
  cout << "Time: ";
  cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << endl;
}
```

**Test 1 Assembly:**

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Time: "
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB1:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB1:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1578:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 12, -16
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 6, -24
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 3, -32
    movl    $100000000, %ebx
    call    _ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv
    movq    %rax, %r12
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    call    rand
    addl    %eax, %ebp
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L2
    call    _ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv
    movl    %ebp, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    %rbx, %rcx
    movabsq $4835703278458516699, %rdx
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    subq    %r12, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, %rax
    sarq    $63, %rcx
    imulq   %rdx
    sarq    $18, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    subq    %rcx, %rsi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1578:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE1:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE1:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB2:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTB2:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1743:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1743:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE2:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE2:
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**Test_2 Assembly**

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Time: "
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB1:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB1:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1578:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 12, -16
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 6, -24
    movl    $4, %edi
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 3, -32
    movl    $100000000, %ebx
    call    _Znwm
    movq    %rax, %rbp
    call    _ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv
    movq    %rax, %r12
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    call    rand
    addl    %eax, 0(%rbp)
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L2
    call    _ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv
    movl    0(%rbp), %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    %rbx, %rcx
    movabsq $4835703278458516699, %rdx
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    subq    %r12, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, %rax
    sarq    $63, %rcx
    imulq   %rdx
    sarq    $18, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    subq    %rcx, %rsi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1578:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE1:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE1:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB2:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTB2:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1743:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1743:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE2:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE2:
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: I would say that 30ms is within the margin of error. Have you tried running the tests multiple times and averaging the numbers?

Comment: Yes, the results are very consistent

Comment: First step: the code you show could be compiled any which way by the compiler. Please provide the generated assembly code in both cases.

Comment: I'd also say that's within the margin of error. And why do you expect them to be different? Both are updating a memory location.  Stack vs. heap will only make a difference on allocation od deallocation.

Comment: Then think of it this way, you are doing a *hundred million iterations*, is 30ms *really* significant? And how often would you expect do do similar things?

Comment: @Paul I don' expect them to be different (at least by much), I'm asking about the difference.

Comment: Also you might want to try e.g. `int* p = &x;` to see if it's *really* about heap versus stack. As well as try it *without* optimizations.

Comment: 30 milliseconds is 3%. It's not going to be anything to do with heap vs. stack. Just maybe a slightly different set of generated code. Show us that assembly code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Percentage wise, yes.

Comment: Is this release or debug build code?

Comment: Given that the version allocating memory on the heap has undefined behavior (the variable isn't initialized) it can finish instantly! First step is clearly to use `int(0)`. Of course, it is likely that the `int` still overflows which means that actually both versions remain undefined behavior. You may want to use `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You're right, I missed that.  They perform the same when using int(0).

Answer (score 1):

With an optimizing compiler, access to variables should be the same regardless of their location in memory.  The compiler may set up a pointer then dereference the pointer to get to the value.

**Other factors:**

- Variable is outside program's space, so OS must load in correct
  memory page.
- Hardware may have different memory access times for different memory
  address ranges.
- Processor's data cache is skewing the result by storing the value.